# Firebase: Firestore transactions not defined?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm new to Firebase and am reading the docs to learn.

I am currently using Firestore instead of the Database and to be honest, I am not super sure about the pro / cons of each.

In their tutorials for [reading and writing data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write) to a Database they have the following code regarding [transactions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions):

```js
function toggleStar(postRef, uid) {
  postRef.transaction(function(post) {
    if (post) {
      if (post.stars && post.stars[uid]) {
        post.starCount--;
        post.stars[uid] = null;
      } else {
        post.starCount++;
        if (!post.stars) {
          post.stars = {};
        }
        post.stars[uid] = true;
      }
    }
    return post;
  });
}
```

which is meant to mitigate race conditions / corruption to the variable `stars` in this case.

My question is what is the Firestore equivalent of `transaction` e.g.

```js
import firebase from 'firebase'


const postId = 1
const firestorePostRef = firebase.firestore().collection('posts').doc(postId)

// throws an error that firestorePostRef.transaction is not defined
firestorePostRef.transaction( (post) => {
  if (post) {
    // ...
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase Firestore has the same functionality. Read data and at the same operation write over something like :

```
// Create a reference to the SF doc.
var sfDocRef = db.collection("cities").doc("SF");

db.runTransaction(function(transaction) {
    return transaction.get(sfDocRef).then(function(sfDoc) {
        if (!sfDoc.exists) {
            throw "Document does not exist!";
        }

        var newPopulation = sfDoc.data().population + 1;
        if (newPopulation <= 1000000) {
            transaction.update(sfDocRef, { population: newPopulation });
            return newPopulation;
        } else {
            return Promise.reject("Sorry! Population is too big.");
        }
    });
}).then(function(newPopulation) {
    console.log("Population increased to ", newPopulation);
}).catch(function(err) {
    // This will be an "population is too big" error.
    console.error(err);
});
```

Here the related documents [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions)